# AKS pod out of memory

Tags: azure, out-of-memory, azure-aks, azure-automation

I have a issue in which in AKS my POD goes out of memory because of a spike i.e. say a message has large amount of data then it makes the POD down. I have multiple PODs running so the execution is transferred to next POD however it also goes down as it is having the same amount of memory and as a result entire application goes down because of 1 spike.
I would like to know a method to autoscale the memory of next POD as 1st goes down because of out of memory issue.
Let me know your thoughts as how can we resolve this process.

I went through AKS docs. It does provide options to autoscale however I don't see an option to autoscale the metrics e.g. CPU, Memory etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes autoscale based on resource consumption generally goes with [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) which scales to more pods if the same group of pods are having higher resource consumption, or [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) which increase resource of the pod spec when monitoring spots higher usage. HPA works by default in AKS and VPA addon is under preview (although you can always install it with helm).

"autoscaler" in AKS typically means the cluster-autoscaler, the main job is to populate new *nodes* when pods stuck in pending due to no node to schedule on. It works well in combo with HPA. i.e., HPA scales new pods --> pods stuck in pending --> cluster-autoscaler scales up new nodes to land the pod.

In your situation of the spike, the next question is how much memory will the offending workload need. VPA probably plays well in this respect, as it [can increase memory request as pod gets oomkilled](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#custom-memory-bump-up-after-oomkill). This is rather useful in "unknown" workload, but I can imagine in some situation the rescue might not come in timely depend on the app's time-wise requirement.

Another approach one can take is to use a fairly generous limit and observe with monitoring, then dial down the memory limit gradually as the project progress.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think VPA will help. Thanks for your suggestion.